# Martingale, Filtration of $\sigma$ -Fields and Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, martingales

> Suppose $\mathcal{F}_n$ is a filtration of $\sigma$-algebras (that means $F_1\subset F_2\subset...\subset F_n$), prove that
>   $X_n=E(X|\mathcal{F}_n)$ is a martingale.

My motivation was to use the law of total expectation with this fact that I proved earlier:

For $\sigma$- fields $\mathcal{F}_{1}\subset \mathcal{F}_2 $ and r.v X, $ E(E(X|\mathcal{F}_2)|\mathcal{F}_1)=E(X|\mathcal{F}_1)$

sub 1,2 for n-1,n and we get:

$$E(X_n|X_1,....X_{n-1})\overset{*}{=}E(X_n|\mathcal{F}_{n-1})=E(E(X|\mathcal{F}_{n})|\mathcal{F}_{n-1})=E(X|\mathcal{F}_{n-1})=X_{n-1}$$

Where the only thing I need to prove that I don't know how to justify is why $$E(X_n|X_1,....X_{n-1})=E(X_n|\mathcal{F}_{n-1})$$ (if that is even true). Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: You do not need to write that quantity at all. Look at your steps again.Your solution is correct.

Comment: I still want to know why it's true, thank you though

Comment: The equality does not hold always.

Comment: But it holds in this case? If so, why?

Comment: No it does not hold in this case. This equality is not general.

Comment: I'm confused, you just said the solution is correct..Can you elaborate/give an alternative proof?

Comment: Your solution is correct. That equality, however, should not be there, because that equality is wrong. Your solution is correct since that incorrect equality does not hamper your solution.

Comment: Ok, I see, but by the definition of martingale we learned that $X_n$ is a martingale if $E(X_n|X_1,...,X_{n-1})=X_{n-1}$  so that's why I think that without that equality the proof is incomplete.

Comment: That is NOT a correct definition of martingale. The correct definition is just via filtration $\mathcal F_n$ with $X_n\in \mathcal F_n$.

Comment: This is from wikipedia:

A basic definition of a discrete-time martingale is a discrete-time stochastic process (i.e., a sequence of random variables) $X_1, X_2, X_3, ...$ that satisfies for any time n,

${\displaystyle \mathbf {E} (\vert X_{n}\vert )<\infty }, \ 
{\displaystyle \mathbf {E} (X_{n+1}\mid X_{1},\ldots ,X_{n})=X_{n}.}$

Seems like the definition I mentioned, no?

Comment: I may be sleepy now, but this is not the standard definition I know. Go through any book, for example. This is where the sigma-field is $\sigma(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ whereas the martingale can be defined for any filtration $\mathcal F_n$. But I think you can argue that since $\sigma(X_1,...,X_n)\subset \mathcal F_n$, by tower property reductions can be done. But I am quite certain this equality you mentioned does not hold in general.

Comment: Note that the more natural filtration here is $\mathcal F_n$. By your definition of $X_n$, $X_n\in\mathcal F_n$. So define the martingale in terms of filtration $\mathcal F_n$ only.

Comment: Ok, so in that case I need to prove that the 2 definitions are equivalent

Comment: Yeah, try that. But can that be true? Note $\sigma(X_1,...,X_n)\subset\mathcal F_n$ and the inclusion may be strict, meaning you have more information in $\mathcal F_n$. What is $E(X_{n+1}|\mathcal \Sigma_n)$? expected value of $X_{n+1}$ given $\Sigma_n$. So if $\Sigma_n$ is larger or smaller, then should we always expect the expected value of $X_{n+1}$ to be same? As I said, I'm too sleepy, but think about it. I'll do the thinking later.

Comment: Yea that's a good question for sure, thank you for all your help:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation (using the tower property of conditional expectation) shows that $E[X_k\mid \mathcal F_{k-1}]=X_{k-1}$ for $k=2,3,\ldots,n$. This means that $(X_k)_{k=1}^n$ is an $(\mathcal F_k)_{k=1}^n$-martingale.

Now *define* the filtration $\mathcal F_k^X:=\sigma(X_1,\ldots, X_k)$, $k=1,2,\ldots,n$. Clearly $\mathcal F^X_k\subset\mathcal F_k$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,n$. A second application of the tower property  shows that $E[X_k\mid\mathcal F^X_{k-1}]=X_{k-1}$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,n$. That is, $(X_k)_{k=1}^n$ is also an $(\mathcal F^X_k)_{k=1}^n$-martingale. If no particular filtration is being used, this latter notion is what is meant if one says that "$(X_k)_{k=1}^n$ is a martingale".